# set Audio Attributes in SoundPool.Builder class for API 21

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

I am following an Android Programming video lecture series which was designed in the pre-API 21 times. Hence it tells me to create a SoundPool variable in the following manner.

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
//SoundPool(int maxStreams, int streamType, int srcQuality)
```

However, I want to use this SoundPool for API 21 as well. So, I am doing this:

```
if((android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) == 21){
    sp21 = new SoundPool.Builder();
    sp21.setMaxStreams(5);
    sp = sp21.build();
}
else{
    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
}
```

sp21 is a variable of `Builder` type for API 21 and sp is of `SoundPool` type.

This works very well with my AVD having API 21 and real device having API 19. (Haven't tried with a real device with API 21 but I think it will work well). Now, I want to set the `streamType` to `USAGE_MEDIA` in the if-block before `sp = sp21.build();`. So I type:

```
sp21.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA);
```

But the Lint marks it in red and says:

> The method setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes) in the type
>   SoundPool.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (int)

I know that even if I do not set it to USAGE_MEDIA it will be set to the same by default. But I am asking for future reference if I have to set it to something else like : USAGE_ALARM.

How should I proceed ?

Please Help!

I have referred to [Audio Attributes](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes.html), [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html), [SoundPool.builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.Builder.html) and [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An AudioAttributes instance is built through its builder, AudioAttributes.Builder.

You can use it in the following way.

```
sp21.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
.build());
```

Ref:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html

Comment: forgot to include.setMaxStreams(5) in line #3

Answer (score 21):

I have something to add here. 
I was using SoundPool in my game app to play small and simple ogg audio files. It was working fine even on emulators with API 21. Today I decided to modify it to use SoundPool.Builder().

I looked at Android's SoundPool.Builder document. It says there

```
public static class
SoundPool.Builder
extends Object
java.lang.Object
↳   android.media.SoundPool.Builder
Class Overview
Builder class for SoundPool objects.
```

Note the line "Builder class for SoundPool objects."
So SoundPool.Builder() creates SoundPool object.
SoundPool() also creates SoundPool object. So this is what I did.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        AudioAttributes audioAttrib = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        mSound = new SoundPool.Builder().setAudioAttributes(audioAttrib).setMaxStreams(6).build();
    }
    else {

        mSound = new SoundPool(6, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }
```

mSound is declared as

```
    private SoundPool mSound;
```

Rest of the code (where I load, play, stop, release sound) remains exactly as it was earlier. And it is working in API 21 and earlier versions

Hope this helps you all

Comment: This answer is better.

Comment: the same applies to calling the MediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes() method