# android studio: sound pool deprecated. Try using soundpool.build()

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, soundpool

After I compile the code, if received a msg which notified that the soundpool is deprecated. I found out that soundpool has been replaced that `soundpool.build()`.

I edited the code from:

```
this.mSoundPool = new SoundPool(Cocos2dxSound.MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_STREAMS_I9100, 
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Cocos2dxSound.SOUND_QUALITY);
```

to:

```
this.mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().Cocos2dxSound.MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_STREAMS_I9100 
                               .AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC .Cocos2dxSound.SOUND_QUALITY);
```

Now I received error.

Can someone enlighten me on how can I edit the code to correct this?

Comment: Can you share the error you encounter ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Brackets are unbalanced here:

```
this.mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().Cocos2dxSound.MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_STREAMS_I9100 
                           .AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC .Cocos2dxSound.SOUND_QUALITY);
```

Try something like this syntax:

```
this.mSoundPool.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
.setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
.setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
.build());
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210921/set-audio-attributes-in-soundpool-builder-class-for-api-21)